# How do you store a PHP date in a variable?

Tags: php

I'm trying to do this, but it's not working:

```
$date  = "on" date('l, F jS') "at" date('g:i:s A');
```

so that it will output:

```
on Day, Month 00th, at 0:00 PM
```

(^ current date)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the string concatenation [operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
$date  = "on " . date('l, F jS') . ", at " . date('g:i:s A');
```